# How to Access a Struct in a Class through a Function in Main?

Tags: c++, function, class, oop

I'm using a function `void displayStudent(Student stu)`, which displays the student's info. In my `main()`, I did this (all the parameters have been created in `main()` respectively already, and `Student` is my class):

```
Student student1(name1, id1, dept1, year1);

displayStudent(student1);
```

Now, in my display function, here is my syntax which works for everything correctly besides the `name` of the student:

```
void displayStudent(Student stu) {

    // Does not work, gives error saying "no type named 'type"
    // and no operator "<<" matches these operands.
    cout << "Name: " << stu.getName() << endl;

    cout << "ID Number: " << stu.getidNumber() << endl;
    cout << "Department: " << stu.getDepartment() << endl;
    cout << "Year: " << stu.getYear() << endl;;
}
```

Furthermore, for info here are my getter/setter functions for the `name` in `Student.cpp`, and the struct `Name` in `Student.h`, which looks like this:

```
struct Name {
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
};
```

The variables in this instance of `Student` have already been initialized with random info from another function in this `Student.cpp` file:

```
void Student::setName(Name n) {
    name.firstName = n.firstName;
    name.lastName = " " + n.lastName;
}

Name Student::getName() const {
    return name;
}
```

Essentially, what I can't figure out is, why can I display everything but the `name` in my `main()`? How do I fix this to access elements of the `name` struct in this instance of `Student`? I initialized them earlier like this:

```
Student::Student(Name a, int b, string c, Year d) {

    // Assigns student info to the 4 parameter variables 
    a.firstName = "Roger";
    a.lastName = "Federer";
    b = 12345;
    c = "Art";
    d = SENIOR;

    name.firstName = a.firstName;
    name.lastName = " " + a.lastName;

    idNumber = b;

    department = c;

    year = d;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to print `stu.getName()`, which is a `Name`. But you never told the compiler how to print a `Name`.

Comment: How do I go about doing that? I am so lost in trying to get it. Do I need to create a temporary Name n in this display function?

Comment: The error message says "I don't know how to call `operator<<` on `Name`". The answer is to write an overload for the function `operator<<` which takes a `Name`, which the linked answer shows you how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
cout << "Name: " << stu.getName() << endl;
```

`stu.getName()` returns a `Name` struct, but by default the compiler doesn't know how to print a `Name` struct to an `std::ostream`, like `std::cout`, when using `operator<<`.  So you need to implement your own `operator<<` overload for printing a `Name`, eg:

```
struct Name {
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
};

// add this!
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Name &name) {
    return out << name.firstName << " " << name.lastName;
}
```

---

On a side note, there is code in your `Student` constructor that does not belong there:

```
Student::Student(Name a, int b, string c, Year d) {

    /* these assignments do not belong here!!! The caller
       is responsible for providing the appropriate values
       when it calls Student()...

    // Assigns student info to the 4 parameter variables 
    a.firstName = "Roger";
    a.lastName = "Federer";
    b = 12345;
    c = "Art";
    d = SENIOR;

    For example:

    Name name1;
    name1.firstName = "Roger";
    name1.lastName = "Federer";
    int id1 = 12345;
    string dept1 = "Art";
    Year year1 = SENIOR;

    Student student1(name1, id1, dept1, year1);
    */

    name.firstName = a.firstName;
    name.lastName = /*" " +*/ a.lastName; // <-- the space character does not belong, either!
    // which can be simplified to just this!
    // name = a;

    idNumber = b;

    department = c;

    year = d;
}
```

And same with `setName()`:

```
void Student::setName(Name n) {
    name.firstName = n.firstName;
    name.lastName = /*" " +*/ n.lastName; // <--

    // or, simply:
    // name = n;
}
```

Comment: This was super helpful, thank you so much! This fixed my issue and I appreciate you commenting on my other code as well.